# Need to match <template>(anything)</template>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, templating

Here's the problem,
The match must not also match 
(anything)
(anything), only the first set.

Here's jsFiddle where I've been trouble shooting this.

http://jsfiddle.net/UFTR2/

```
var templates = '<template mini-dash-ytd>'+
                    '<span class="mini-dash-title">{{title}}</span>'+
                    '<span class="mini-dash-metric">{{value}}</span>'+
                '</template>'+
                '<template mini-dash-yesterday>'+
                    '<span class="mini-dash-title">{{title}}</span>'+
                    '<span class="mini-dash-metric">{{value}}<span class="mini-dash-performance-{{performance}}"></span></span>'+
                '</template>';

function templatitFind(string) {
    var regex = new RegExp("<template\\s+"+string+">([^;]*)</template>","ig");
    var val = templates.match(regex);
    if (val !== null) return val[0];
}

$(function () {
    console.log(templatitFind('mini-dash-ytd'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adeneo is right about parsing it as HTML, you can also fix your issue by making your repetition operator lazy and remove the global flag. Also, the first element in the match array produced is always the full expression match. You need to get the second element for getting only the content of the capturing group.

Lines changed:

```
var regex = new RegExp("<template\\s+"+string+">([^;]*?)</template>","i");
```

And

```
if (val) return val[1]; //null is falsey
```

Comment: One problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UFTR2/3/ -- it fails when there's only one line of code in between the matches.

Comment: @user1529598, It doesn't work because the last template contains the `;`, which your capturing group doesn't capture. You can change your capturing group to capture all characters `(.*?)` and it will work. However, make sure you also take the `val[1]` element instead of `val[0]`.

Comment: That works, and one more thing I had to do to get it to finally work was remove all end of line characters on text:

    templates = i.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,'');

Before processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks almost like HTML to me, so why do you need a regex ?

```
var templates = '<template mini-dash-ytd>'+
                  '<span class="mini-dash-title">{{title}}</span>'+
                  '<span class="mini-dash-metric">{{value}}</span>'+
                '</template>'+
                '<template mini-dash-yesterday>'+
                  '<span class="mini-dash-title">{{title}}</span>'+
                  '<span class="mini-dash-metric">{{value}}<span class="mini-dash-performance-{{performance}}"></span></span>'+
                '</template>';

var elems = $('<div />').append(templates);
var first = elems.find('template[mini-dash-ytd]').get(0).outerHTML;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UFTR2/2/)

Comment: I started with making it an element. But when I had {{if elem id="{{elem}} endif}} -- the string would be changed to something I couldn't work with.